# How can I manuel resize Table fields?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, asp.net-core

So I createt in Asp.Net this table:

```
<div class="table-container">
  <table id="planningTable">
    <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Planung</th>
      @for (int week = 1; week <= 52; week++) {
        <th>@week</th>
      }
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @foreach (var projectEvent in Model.ProjectEvents) {
      <tr>
        <td>@projectEvent.Project.Name</td>
        @for (int week = 1; week <= 52; week++) {
          var eventType = projectEvent.EventValues[week - 1];
          string styleAttr = "";
          string cellClass = "";
          if (eventType.HasValue) {
            switch (eventType.Value) {
              case EventType.Sprint:
                styleAttr = "background-color: red;";
                cellClass = "sprint-cell";
                break;
              case EventType.Firefighting:
                styleAttr = "background-color: orange;";
                cellClass = "firefighting-cell";
                break;
            }
          }
          <td class="@cellClass" style="@styleAttr"></td>
        }
      </tr>
    }
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

which it make look like that:

[Visual Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JkLpy.png)

as you can see I already created the visual functionality that the visuel respond is there to resize the red Fields in this table.

My goal is to resize ist that it goes from that for example:
[before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1qTAm.png)

[After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hzrZa.png)

so that the user can resize the fields as he wants

thats my js script so far and I got the visual respond but I dont know how I can actually implement the resizing over the columns like in my example:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
  const rows = document.querySelectorAll('#planningTable tbody tr');

  rows.forEach(row => {
    mergeAndEnableResizingForColoredCells(row);
  });
});

function mergeAndEnableResizingForColoredCells(row) {
  let lastColor = null;
  let mergeStart = null;
  let colspan = 0;

  row.querySelectorAll('td').forEach((cell, index) => {
    const currentColor = cell.style.backgroundColor;

    if (currentColor === lastColor && currentColor !== '') {
      colspan++;
    } else {
      finalizeMerge(mergeStart, colspan);
      colspan = 1;
      mergeStart = cell;
    }

    lastColor = currentColor;

    // Am Ende der Reihe
    if (index === row.cells.length - 1) {
      finalizeMerge(mergeStart, colspan);
    }
  });
}

function finalizeMerge(cell, colSpan) {
  if (cell && colSpan > 1) {
    cell.colSpan = colSpan;
    for (let i = 1; i < colSpan; i++) {
      cell.parentElement.deleteCell(cell.cellIndex + 1);
    }
    applyResizing(cell);
  } else if (cell && cell.style.backgroundColor !== '') {
    applyResizing(cell);
  }
}

function applyResizing(cell) {
  cell.style.resize = 'horizontal';
  cell.style.overflow = 'auto';
}
```

and what makes it even harder, I cant use stuff like angualar or react just normal Asp.Net html stuff

Comment: Do you want Plugin to resize columns by mouse drag or touch? like:[jQuery dataTables ColResize](https://github.com/dhobi/datatables.colResize)

Comment: I want to resize a certain filled cell so that the filled cell is at the start 2 columns long and i want to resize it that its 3 columns long for example